# Symfony login from an external application

Tags: php, authentication, symfony, request, cors

Is there a way to login in a symfony app from an external application ?

I tried to create a custom authenticator. With it, I can make working the login processus through the custom authenticator in a same environment, but when I try from an external app, I face to CORS errors : "Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request"

The process I tried :

- The external app ask for a token on the symfony app (get request)
- with this token, and a mail in the body, a post request trigger the authenticator (post request), this request is good in postman, it returns me the home page of the app with a connected user
- I don't know what to do next to make it work correctly

Is anyone have an idea ?

Thanks by advance

UPDATE 1 :

The code that I tried :

```
/**
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function authenticate(Request $request): Passport
{
    $apiToken = $request->headers->get('X-AUTH-TOKEN-OAV');
    $sessionId = $request->headers->get('X-AUTH-TOKEN-SESSION');
    $session = $request->getSession();
    $session->setId($sessionId);

    if (null === $apiToken) {
        // The token header was empty, authentication fails with HTTP Status
        // Code 401 "Unauthorized"
        throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('X-AUTH-TOKEN-OAV attendu dans les headers');
    }

    $content = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
    if (\is_array($content) && \array_key_exists('userEmail', $content)) {
        $email = $content['userEmail'];
        $request->getSession()->set('email', $email);
    }

    // On inscrit l'email en session
    $email = $request->getSession()->get('email');
    // On vérifie la validité du token et on incrémente la durée de sa validité
    $this->checkTokenValidity($apiToken, true);
    return new Passport(new UserBadge('mail@mail.fr'), new PasswordCredentials('pswd!!'));
}
```

And in the html page to simulate external app :

```
{% block body %}
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-o88AwQnZB+VDvE9tvIXrMQaPlFFSUTR+nldQm1LuPXQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    let tokenOav = '';
    let sessionOav = '';
    function sendSetRequest() {
        console.info('Sending set request');
        console.log(tokenOav.value);
        console.log('start');
        console.log(sessionOav)
        console.log('********')
        let set_params = {
            "action": "action_set"
        };
        return $.ajax({
            data: set_params,
            url: "https://my-site.fr/home",
            headers: {
                'X-AUTH-TOKEN-OAV': tokenOav.value,
                'withCredentials': true,
                'X-AUTH-TOKEN-SESSION': sessionOav
            },
            type: 'post',
            success: function (result) {
                window.location.href = "https://my-site.fr/home";
            }
        });
    }
    function sendGetRequest() {
        console.info('Sending get request');
        let get_params = {
            "action": "action_get"
        };
        return $.ajax({
            data: get_params,
            url: 'https://my-site.fr/api/generer-token?api_token=TOKEN',
            type: 'get',
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
                tokenOav = result.token;
                sessionOav = result.session_id;
                $("#cntr_debug2").html(result);
            }
        });
    }
    function callApi() {
        sendGetRequest().then(sendSetRequest);
    }
</script>
<form><!---Removed form submit url-->
    <input type="text" id="keyName" value="testValue">
    <!---Id attribute added to input field to be submitted--->
    <input type="button" onclick="callApi()" value="Submit">
    <!---Input type is button NOT submit--->
</form>
```

Comment: Can you show the code you tried ? Also, did you tried to fix the CORS issue ?

Comment: Hello, ty for your answer !

Yep In tied to fix the CORS issues, vainly :/

See update 1 for code examples

Comment: Browsers do not allow execution of  Ajax requests from a different domain if CORS is not configured to allow it. You can use the Nelmio CORS bundle to configure cross origin requests. https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioCorsBundle

Comment: @PatrickKenekayoro Thank you for your answer ! I managed to make it works with a simple post form to replace the post Ajax request. I don't know if there is a better way to do it. If someone have a better solution, share it pls :D